# Is it possible to set cookies with swfObject?

Tags: javascript, cookies, swfobject

Working on script, that should receive cookies and settings via link. Well cookies might be passed otherwise, but they need to be passed to the swfObject so that script could work correctly.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is wrong with setting cookies, using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. SWFObject has nothing to do with cookies (or Flash Shared Objects, for that matter). You will need to handle cookies using external JavaScript. [PPK has a great script you can use](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

If you need to pass data to your SWF via SWFObject, you'd extract the cookie data using your own JavaScript, then add it to your flashvars object before embedding the SWF. See http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/advanced-options-with-dynamic-publishing/ for instructions on how to use SWFObject, including passing flashvars.